# beautifulsoup - obtaining the tag and it's parent from the text inside?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Using beautifulsoup it is possible to do the following:

```
for heading in soup.find_all('h1'):
   print(heading.text)

Top Rated Movies
```

However, is there a method to extract the tags themselves, given the text? A way of working backwards from the above example, something like:

```
soup.find_tag('Top Rated Movies')

h1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite a few ways.

If you know the *exact* text, you can use `text` or `string` argument like

```py
tags = soup.find_all(True, string="Top Rated Movies")
```

for more ways to use the `string` argument, like when you only know part of the text, you can check out the relevant section of [the documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-string-argument).

---

Also, for partial text you can use `lambda`

```py
tags = soup.find_all(lambda x: x.name and x.text and 'Top Rated Movies' in x.text)
```

or, using `select` and the [`-soup-contains`](https://facelessuser.github.io/soupsieve/selectors/pseudo-classes/#:-soup-contains) selector

```py
tags = soup.select(':-soup-contains("Top Rated Movies")')
```

Of course, with the partial-match methods, you'll end up getting the parent tags as well, but you can filter them out with

```py
tags = [t for t in tags if not [p for p in t.parents if p in tags]]
```

or, if you're sure the target tag doesn't have any more tags nested within it,

```py
tags = [t for t in tags if t.find() is None]
```

although, in that case, you could have used the `:-soup-contains-own` selector and not needed to filter.

(Please note that you probably need to use the `html5lib` [parser](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser) for pseudo-classes like `-soup-contains`.)

---

---

If you want the tag name specifically, follow any of the above with:

```py
for t in tags: print(t.name)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
for tag in soup.findAll(True, text="Top Rated Movies"):
    print(tag.name)
```